# Creational design pattern that allows configuration of objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, factory, builder-pattern

With the factory pattern we abstract the creation of objects. But what if we need a specific configuration of an object that depends on the calling context?
Example:

So I have a `Builder` pattern for creating some types of objects that share the same interface
E.g.

```
private EmployeeBuilder createEmployee(EmployeeDataSource e) {  
    if(e instanceof Engineer) {
       return new EngineerEmployeeBuilder((EngineerDataSource) e);  
    }  
    else if(e instanceof Manager) {  
       return new ManagerBuilder((ManagerDataSource) e);  
    }  
    else if(e instanceof Salesman) {
       return new SalesmanBuilder((SalesmanDataSource) e);  
    }  
    // etc  
}
```

So far so good as the calling code can just do something like:

```
Manager m = createEmployee(ManagerDataSource ds).build();
```

The problem I have is that it turns out that I need to make some changes to the builder object but I can not do them inside the `createEmployee` as that is called from places that the change should not happen. E.g. the above snippet could become:

```
EmployeeBuilder eb = createEmployee(EmployeeDataSource ds);  
if(eb instanceof ManagerBuilder) {
    ((ManagerBuilder)eb).setRoleInc(INC_FOR_ROLE);  
}  
Employee e = eb.build();   
// use only Employee here
```

This looks like a code smell and would like to avoid it.
Is there a combination of design patterns I could use to enhance the original approach?

Answer (score 1):

Just add some additional parameters (maybe optional ones) to `createEmployee`, even if those parameters or certain values of them only apply to certain builder types. That gives you the possibility of calling `setRoleInc` inside `createEmployee` when it is required, something along the lines of

```
private EmployeeBuilder createEmployee(EmployeeDataSource e, Role role=ROLE_NONE) {  
    if(e instanceof Engineer) {
       return new EngineerEmployeeBuilder((EngineerDataSource) e);  
    }  
    else if(e instanceof Manager) {  
       var mb = new ManagerBuilder((ManagerDataSource) e);  
       if(role !=ROLE_NONE)
           mb.SetRoleInc(role);
       return mb;
    }  
    else if(e instanceof Salesman) {
       return new SalesmanBuilder((SalesmanDataSource) e);  
    }  
    // etc  
}
```

(For the sake of demonstration, I used C# syntax for optional parameters, which is AFAIK not available/different in Java, but I guess you can transfer the solution to Java by yourself).

Comment: So what if the parameters should be different per type of object? E.g. `Role role` would be applicable only to `Manager`. Or I could have X number after that. How could I generalize this?

Comment: @Jim: by introducing a parameter class which can have different subclasses, for example a base class "Configuration", together with a ManagerConfiguration, SalesmanConfiguration etc. Or by simply providing different overloads of `createEmployee` with different parameters.

Comment: But this assumes that the calling code knows what type `EmployeeDataSource` is so as to pass the concrete `Configuration` right? But then that defeats the purpose of the factory method right? I mean if the calling code was to "know"  that the `EmployeeDataSource` is something that would construct a `Manager` so as to pass a  `ManagerConfiguration` it could just create it on the spot instead of having the factory method. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Jim: for this, it would probably be the best to have a general "Configuration" object which is filled with all potential parameters from the environment which may be useful for those builders, at least one.

Comment: How would that be best defined? Would the API for `Configuration` cover all possible options for each concrete `EmployeeBuilder`?

Comment: @Jim: I think these design decisions are best made in context of a real situation, with real requirements. There are several details which may differ, it does not make much sense to speculate about this using a purely hypothetical case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a repeated typo here.  I assume that

```
if (e instanceof Engineer)
```

should really read

```
if (e instanceof EngineerDataSource)
```

(same story here with Manager and Salesman).  Leave a comment if I'm wrong about that.

My actual problem with what you have here is that your createEmployee method is named incorrectly--it doesn't create an `Employee`.  Rather, it creates an `Employee*Builder*`.

So I'd rename `createEmployee` to `createEmployeeBuilder` and then create a new method (*this* one called `createEmployee`) that looks like

```
private Employee createEmployee(EmployeeDataSource eds) {
  EmployeeBuilder eb = createEmployeeBuilder(eds);
  if (eb instanceof ManagerBuilder) {
    //do special configuration here
  }
  return eb.build();
}
```

You might have to add a parameter or two to this `createEmployee` method, depending on exactly what your special configuration is.

Alternatively, if you can get away with it, just stick that special configuration (in your example, `setRoleInc(INC_FOR_ROLE)`) inside the build() method for ManagerBuilder.  Then you don't need that new `createEmployee` method at all and can just do:

```
Employee e = createEmployeeBuilder(eds).build();
```

(casting if necessary after that point).